# .clang-format: avoid formatting between @code and @endcod

Tags: c++, clang-format

Our code documentation also includes code examples like

```
\** Example
* @code
* int main()
* {
*  return 0;
* }
* @endcode
```

After calling `clang-format` the parts between `@code` and `@endcode` are also formatted, which I do not like. Is there a way to force `clang-format` to avoid formatting statements between `@code` and `@endcode`? Or do I have to extra write extra `\\ clang-format off` and `\\ clang-format on` statements?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found other solution, I think we are obliged to add `//clang-format on` and `//clang-format off`  comment